# Random ImageView - is possible to detect which is showing?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got in my script:

```
   final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(9);
    img.setImageDrawable
            (
                    getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
                            getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            ));
    return view;
    // ^^^ move it here
```

}

with

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
```

Now, I want to make something like this, that every image from this random function opens other activity onClick. Is it possible to make it something:

**if img_3** **is showing, go to NumberOne.java activity onClick?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store whatever image you randomly picked, and go from there.

Edit:

You can set a non-final static variable to hold the id of the photo chosen.

eg: `public static Integer CURRENT_IMAGE = -1;`

When you randomly generate a number make sure to write it to `CURRENT_IMAGE`

```
CURRENT_IMAGE = rnd.nextInt(9);
final String str = "img_" + CURRENT_IMAGE;
img.setImageDrawable(
                getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
                        getActivity().getApplicationContext())
        ));
return view;
// ^^^ move it here
```

After that, you can edit the onclick method to check like so:

```
if(CURRENT_IMAGE == 3){
    //Start activity NumberOne.java...
}else if(CURRENT_IMAGE == 4){
    //Start another activity...
}else{
    // Do whatever
}
```

Update 2:

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(CURRENT_IMAGE == 3){
            //Start activity NumberOne.java...
        }else if(CURRENT_IMAGE == 4){
            //Start another activity...
        }else{
            // Do whatever
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: how? Can You help me with any link or smth?

Comment: Updated main post

Comment: Thanks for help! Can You give a full code for onclicklistener and onclick?

Comment: Another update to the main post. I hope this helps, You should modify it a bit to fit your needs though, as I cannot think for you.